# RSpec error using build Factories instead of create - expected to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've model `ActivityRead` which belongs to three other models (details below). I want to add a FactoryBot generator and try to check if model is valid and possible to save into db. I'm using `build` to call factory instead of `create` which saves to db and in my specs I'm getting an error:

```
  1) ActivityRead associations when new model is created save to DB
     Failure/Error: expect { sample_activity }.to change { ActivityRead.count }.by(1)
       expected `ActivityRead.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Here's my specs:

```
context 'when new model is created' do
  let(:sample_activity) { build(:activity_read) }

  it 'save to DB' do
    expect { sample_activity }.to change { ActivityRead.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```

Factories:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :activity_read do
    user
    journey
    activity
    cms_activity_id { Faker::Number.number }
  end
end
```

`ActivityRead` model

```
class ActivityRead < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :journey
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

The weird is when I use `let(:sample_activity) { create(:activity_read) }` instead of `let(:sample_activity) { build(:activity_read) }` specs will pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered correctly,

> `create` which saves to db

and `build` does only build the object but does not store it to the database. `ActivityRead.count` will trigger a `SELECT COUNT(*) from activity_reads` query which will be empty of course.

You would need to call `save` on the object to save it to the database.

```rb
context 'when new model is created' do
  let(:sample_activity) { build(:activity_read) }

  it 'save to DB' do
    expect { sample_activity.save }.to change { ActivityRead.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```